# SQL copy rows by date until today

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, date, plsql

**FYI THE DATE FORMAT : YYYY.MM.DD and i want to increment every rows by 1 month**

I have the following sample table in excel:

```
id   date    price
1  2013.01.01 20
2  2014.03.01 30
3  2014.04.01 30
4  2010.01.01 10
```

I need to insert to the database to duplicate all rows until today so:

```
id    date   price
1  2013.01.01 20
1  2013.02.01 20
1  2013.03.01 20
1  2013.04.01 20
....
1  2014.10.01 20
2  2014.03.01 30
...
2  2014.10.01 30
...
4  2010.01.01 10
...
4  2010.10.01 10
```

Can you advice me something, my first thought was a JAVA code wich is generating the dates, but the java data function is not my best. And also I want to solve it in SQL or PL/SQL *or maybe excel .*

Comment: How are you inserting your table data in Oracle?

Comment: its already inserted
id,date ( DATE) , price ( number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is really in a table, you could solve this if you have a list of numbers.  Here is one solution:

```
with m as (
      select trunc(sysdate) - min(date) + 1 as numdays
      from tablename t
     ),
     n as (
      select level - 1 as n
      from m
      connect by level <= m.numdays + 1
     )
select id, date + n.n as date, price
from tablename t join
     n
     on date + n.n <= sysdate;
```

EDIT:

To do this by month, I think the following should work:

```
with m as (
      select months_between(trunc(sysdate), min(date)) + 1 as nummonths
      from tablename t
     ),
     n as (
      select level - 1 as n
      from m
      connect by level <= m.nummonths + 1
     )
select id, add_months(date, n.n) as date, price
from tablename t join
     n
     on add_months(date, n.n) <= sysdate;
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I need to increment only by month not by date, could you help me please. I tried to replace add(month,1)  but the with function at sql is not clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the id is unique key in your dataset. you can Transfer this data to Oracle table and then write function to do the rest for you.

```
    SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE test_table(
  2  ID NUMBER,
  3  DATE1 DATE,
  4  price number);
Table created

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1,to_date('2014.10.25','yyyy.mm.dd'),20);
1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(2,to_date('2014.10.27','yyyy.mm.dd'),30);
1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(3,to_date('2014.10.28','yyyy.mm.dd'),30);
1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(4,to_date('2014.10.31','yyyy.mm.dd'),10);
1 row inserted

SQL> commit;
Commit complete

SQL> SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY ID,date1;
        ID DATE1            PRICE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 10/25/2014          20
         2 10/27/2014          30
         3 10/28/2014          30
         4 10/31/2014          10

SQL> 
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test_fill_dup IS
  2  CURSOR c_data IS SELECT ID,date1,price FROM test_table;
  3  BEGIN
  4  
  5  FOR r_data IN c_data LOOP
  6    IF TRUNC(SYSDATE) = trunc(r_data.date1) THEN CONTINUE; END IF;
  7    FOR i IN 1..(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - r_data.date1) LOOP
  8      INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(r_data.id,r_data.date1+i,r_data.price);
  9      END LOOP;
 10      END LOOP;
 11      COMMIT;
 12  END     p_test_fill_dup;
 13  /
Procedure created

SQL> 
SQL> begin
  2    -- Call the procedure
  3    p_test_fill_dup;
  4  end;
  5  /
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY ID,date1;
        ID DATE1            PRICE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 10/25/2014          20
         1 10/26/2014          20
         1 10/27/2014          20
         1 10/28/2014          20
         1 10/29/2014          20
         1 10/30/2014          20
         1 10/31/2014          20
         2 10/27/2014          30
         2 10/28/2014          30
         2 10/29/2014          30
         2 10/30/2014          30
         2 10/31/2014          30
         3 10/28/2014          30
         3 10/29/2014          30
         3 10/30/2014          30
         3 10/31/2014          30
         4 10/31/2014          10
17 rows selected
```

If you want to add month till current month using procedure you can use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test_fill_dup IS
    CURSOR c_data IS SELECT ID,date1,price FROM test_table;
    BEGIN

    FOR r_data IN c_data LOOP
      IF TRUNC(months_between(SYSDATE,r_data.date1))=0 THEN CONTINUE; END IF;

      FOR i IN 1..TRUNC(months_between(SYSDATE,r_data.date1)) LOOP
        INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(r_data.id,add_months(r_data.date1,i),r_data.price);
        END LOOP;
       END LOOP;
       COMMIT;
   END     p_test_fill_dup;
```

Comment: thx but i dont think its good answer i need far more rows, and i need to increment by month not by day. ( and ofc year if it need to turn)

Comment: with your example, how could we know what is month and what is day?

Comment: i edited my question to make sure my date format : yyyy.mm.dd